# Windows folder accessed from Ubuntu; now missing

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, directory

I have Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 7 HB. I had (had since it's no visible in the Windows directory) a folder in Windows whose path was
D:/Edu/MS/Semester 3 Summer. I have Windows 7 partitioned into 2 drives: C and Drive.

I accessed the **Semester 3 Summer** folder from Ubuntu by clicking the **316 OS Volume**(which I believe is the D Drive of my Windows). Now, when I logged back into the Windows, I can no longer see the folder. It has (or had) all my assignments.

How do I get the folder back?

Comment: Please help me as I'm losing other folders too!!! I don't wanna lose my things!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you still access the folder when you boot Ubuntu? If yes, just copy it to an USB drive or such. If the folder can't be accessed in Ubuntu, too, you should probably check the drive for errors - either with `chkdsk` on Windows or `fsck.vfat` (for FAT(32)) on Ubuntu.

Comment: I couldn't access the folder from Ubuntu too.